# Document Cookie not Working on Click Event — Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to set up a simple privacy notice on a site to make them aware that third-party cookies are used. It has a link to review the privacy and cookie policy and an 'OK' option to click if they're happy and don't want to review things.

I'm trying to get it so once the 'OK' is clicked, the message doesn't show again when they come back to the home page, but I can't seem to get it to work?

I've set the `document.cookie` line inside a click handler (for when they click 'OK'), but the message flashes up then immediately disappears without being clicked?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/OoVKOQ

** Note in the Codepen I've commented out the `hideCookieMessage()` function call at the bottom, if you uncomment this you can see the problem.

```
// COOKIE NOTE AND OK BUTTON
var cookieAccept = document.getElementsByClassName("click-wrapper")[0]
var cookieNotice = document.getElementsByClassName("cookie-notice")[0]

// CLICK FUNCTION
cookieAccept.addEventListener("click", function(){

    cookieNotice.style.display="none";
    document.cookie = "accepted=yes;expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 01:00:00 UTC;"

    return document.cookie;

}, false)

// CONTINUES TO HIDE THE COOKIE MESSAGE WHEN RETURNING TO THE HOMEPAGE
function hideCookieMessage() {
    if (document.cookie.length != 0) {
        var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");

        if (nameValueArray[1] = "yes") {
            cookieNotice.style.display="none";
        } else {
            alert("cookie not found")
        }
    }
} 

hideCookieMessage();

console.log(document.cookie)
```

Comment: So you are only going to have one cookie value? You would be better with a method that actually parses the cookie. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework

Comment: @epascarello I'm new to Cookies so that has gone a bit over my head.  How would that help my problem? Feel free to answer as if you're speaking to an idiot so I don't miss anything.

Comment: include the script and you can do `if(docCookies.hasItem("accepted"))` and you can use their setItem method to properly set the cookie.

Comment: @epascarello That worked - thank you so much.  If you post that as an answer I'll happily upvote and mark as correct.